# How to import typescript modules by name?

Tags: typescript, angular, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code to write an app in Angular 2. I'm wondering if it's possible to create an entry in some project setting to allow me to import modules by name. Currently I have to write `import * from <long path>` for modules I create. I would like to define a mapping `'name': <long path>` somewhere and then be able to write `import * from <name>` in my files, this way when I move the path of the module I don't have to go change all the files. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

> this way when I move the path of the module I don't have to go change all the files. Is this possible

Not unless you use split the project into little `node_modules`.

Having configurable paths for module resolution is tracked here : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5039

Comment: yeah, but I would like to develop the modules in conjunction with my app, and then separate them out later as node_modules. It's too much overhead to do this from the beginning.

Comment: Agreed. Can't be done at the moment. Note that your IDE can make it easier : https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript#relative-paths